# Where can I find the implementation of strncpy() function in GCC source code?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have download the source code of gcc, using this command:

```
svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk SomeLocalDir
```

Who can tell me where can I find the implementation of standard library function strncpy()?

Thank you.

Comment: it will be in libc, rather than gcc source:  http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=string/strncpy.c;hb=HEAD

Comment: And you might want to [read this](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: Note that gcc generally uses whatever library is provided by the OS.  On Linux systems, that's glibc; on most other systems it will be something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcc` doesn't actually contain the source of `strncpy`, as `gcc` contains the compiler code and not the standard library code.

You want the source from GNU libc (glibc):

This is a link to the current trunk implementation of `strncpy.c` in glibc.

http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strncpy.c;h=f6ee27832da95d9da9aef8a6fcf73f53f997c796;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 5):

These answers are correct, in that a standard C library will implement `strncpy`. *However*, gcc has [builtin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) functions that may be generated by the compiler - as intermediate code, not linked function calls - of which `strncpy` is one. These can be explicitly disabled with `-fno-builtin`.

In the gcc source tree, you can find the code generation patters in `gcc/builtins.c` and `gcc/builtins.def`. Being instantiated in the intermediate representation allows for far more aggressive optimizations, and elimination of call overheads.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have better luck [looking in glibc](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strncpy.c) instead.

Answer (score 0):

strncpy belong to C runtime library, so you could find it in glibc instead of GCC(the compiler).